# error by upgrading angular from 7.2.15: minTimeout is greater than maxTimeout

Tags: angular, angular-upgrade

I have a current angular app with 7.2.15 and I tried to upgrade with the command

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
```

I became this error and I don't understand why:

```
Using package manager: 'npm'
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 48 dependencies.
Fetching dependency metadata from registry...
Error fetching metadata for '@angular/cli': minTimeout is greater than maxTimeout
```

I followed the guide from [update.angular.io](https://update.angular.io/#7.2:8.0).

Has someone any ideas why it happens? I don't have declaration of variables like minTimeout or maxTimeout in my project

Answer (score 0):

I came across this error when installing packages via ng add. I solved this by editing the .npmrc in my userfolder (Windows: C:/users//.npmrc). There were 2 settings

```
fetch-retry-mintimeout 15000
fetch-retry-maxtimeout 90000
```

uncommenting these line with # solved the problem for me.
Maybe you can set those by

```
npm config set fetch-retry-mintimeout <value>
npm config set fetch-retry-maxtimeout <value>
```

I didn't test this though.

Answer (score 0):

Commented the lines by adding # in .npmrc file:

```
#fetch-retry-mintimeout=30000
#fetch-retry-maxtimeout=120000
```

It will use the default values for mintimeout and maxtimeout 10000 and 60000 respectively