# Ng Update does not work with Error "minTimeout is greater than maxTimeout"

Tags: angular

Until now whenever i wanted to update my Angular dependencies with "ng update" as stated [on this page](https://update.angular.io/#8.2:9.0), i got this error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: minTimeout is greater than maxTimeout
```

This is a detailed log:

```
[error] Error: minTimeout is greater than maxTimeout
    at Object.exports.timeouts (C:\myprojectlocation\node_modules\promise-retry\node_modules\retry\lib\retry.js:28:11)
    at Object.exports.operation (C:\myprojectlocation\node_modules\promise-retry\node_modules\retry\lib\retry.js:4:26)
    at promiseRetry (C:\myprojectlocation\node_modules\promise-retry\index.js:23:23)
    at remoteFetch (C:\myprojectlocation\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\index.js:329:10)
    at conditionalFetch (C:\myprojectlocation\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\index.js:239:10)
    at C:\myprojectlocation\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\index.js:148:18
    at tryCatcher (C:\myprojectlocation\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\myprojectlocation\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:547:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (C:\myprojectlocation\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:604:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\myprojectlocation\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:649:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (C:\myprojectlocation\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:729:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (C:\myprojectlocation\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:93:12)
    at _drainQueue (C:\myprojectlocation\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:86:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (C:\myprojectlocation\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:102:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (C:\myprojectlocation\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:15:14)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21)
```

As very this moment, i have the version **8.2.13** and wanted to update to **9.0**. And as the instruction page suggests, i run this command:

ng update @angular/core@8 @angular/cli@8

Why do i still have this error?

PS: With the older versions (maybe while updating from 4 to 5/6) i had the same error. I ended up creating a new project with the newer cli, and manually copied all files to the new project.. I am not sure if this manual approach is really not "healthier" than this suggested process, in case of a simple Angular app where you do not have any compatibility issues.

Comment: Worked for me after commenting the lines in .npmrc: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77433643/1222752

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same issue, while updating my angular v7 to v8. Later on I remember that I've changed some config setting in npm. I had changed below two setting sometime back.

```
fetch-retry-mintimeout = 100000
fetch-retry-maxtimeout = 1200000
```

I just reverted the above change back to default values i.e

```
npm config set fetch-retry-maxtimeout=60000
npm config set fetch-retry-mintimeout=10000
```

And that resolved this "minTimeout is greater than maxTimeout".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is easy to fix. What I don't understand is why most people seem to not have the problem.

It's pointing you to C:\myprojectlocation\node_modules\promise-retry\node_modules\retry\lib\retry.js:28:11

```js
if (opts.minTimeout > opts.maxTimeout) {
```

If you add debug information there, you'll find that in the ng update error case, opts.minTimeout and opts.maxTimeout are strings instead of numbers and thus, the check in line 28 does not work (in my case '8000' > '10000' was true of course). So just add e.g. the following code in front of line 28:

```js
if (typeof opts.minTimeout === 'string') {
  opts.minTimeout = 1 * opts.minTimeout;
}
if (typeof opts.maxTimeout === 'string') {
  opts.maxTimeout = 1 * opts.maxTimeout;
}
```

(Where these 'wrong' options are coming from, I have not checked. However, it will work with the mentioned fix)

Answer (score 0):

1) You must update your local CLI first.

The correct CLI update is:

```
npm uninstall @angular/cli --save
npm install @angular/cli --save
ng update @angular/cli
```

2) Make sure you are using **Node 10.13** or later.

Run `node --version` for check it.

If you need an update [check it](https://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/update-node-js-latest-version/) or use [Node Version Manager (NVM)](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm).

- NVM is a Bash script that lets you download and manage different versions of node.

3) Run `ng update @angular/core@8 @angular/cli@8`

4) Run `ng update @angular/core @angular/cli` which should bring you to **version 9 of Angular**.

Answer (score 0):

What I see is you already have `angular 8.2.13` and again when you will run `ng update @angular/core@8 @angular/cli@8` it will try to upgrade to the latest version of angular 8 which you are already in.

so migrating from angular to angular 8 might be the first problem. So you can try

```
   ng update @angular/core @angular/cli
```

It will upgrade to angular 9 from angular9

I also did the manual upgrade by creating a new angular project with `ng new projName` and manually coping all the file and folder there, I think that is a best option if you have time and resources to do that as it will also take the new folder structure, etc.